# Group Data Plot- Nothing works from past questions

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
                     Geography Population.Estimate Energy.Consump Employed  Year
1   Alameda County, California             1513228     3038.53227   676598  2010 
2    Alpine County, California                1163       17.14083      387  2010
3    Amador County, California               37862      140.65325    15103  2011 
4     Butte County, California              219973      722.73871    90130  2011
5 Calaveras County, California               45457      198.95724    17085  2012
6    Colusa County, California               21483       63.77387     9489  2012
```

This is just part of the data from 58 counties.

I want to make a box plot to show x axis -Population and y axis -energy consumption for the years 2010, 2011, 2012. I tried a lot of things but it just doesnt work. Please help me with the plots. I used qplot as well as ggplot. Nothing seems to work on this data :(

I tried this

```
qplot(factor(Year),data=Population,geom="bar",fill=Population.Estimate,weight=En‌​ergy_Consump,position="dodge", main = "Effect of Energy", xlab="Population",ylab="Energy")
```

I tried this too

```
ggplot(Population)+ geom_bar(aes(x=Housing.Units,y=Energy.Consump, fill=factor(Year)),stat="identity")
```

I am struggling to get it right. I tried the other examples in stack overflow, since I am fairly new to R but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this qplot(factor(Year),data=Population,geom="bar",fill=Population.Estimate,weight=Energy_Consump,position="dodge",
      main = "Effect of Energy", xlab="Population",ylab="Energy")

Comment: I tried this too ggplot(Population)+ geom_bar(aes(x=Housing.Units,y=Energy.Consump, fill=factor(Year)),stat="identity"). I am struggling to get it right. I tried the other examples in stack overflow, since I am fairly new to R but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Hi Roman, I added the codes which I tried to use to get the plots. They are just above your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you want a boxplot?

Comment: @tootsie_1984 I thinkRoman meant putting the codes in the question itself rather than the comment. I've edited the question to include them in (subject to review).

Comment: Khashaa yep I want it like that. The trouble is I have to do this for 58 counties and what I put is just few of the data. I tried your code and it doesn't give me what I exactly want.

Comment: Though my problem isn't solved yet. I really appreciate everyone's answers :) Especially Khashaa :) Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
ggplot(data=Population, aes(x=Population.Estimate, y=Energy.Consump, fill=as.factor(Year))) + 
 geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity",
       position=position_dodge()) +                        # Thinner lines
 xlab("Population") + ylab("Energy Consumption")
```

[image]

Not this?

```
ggplot(data=Population, aes(x=Year, y=Population.Estimate, fill=Geography)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity",
       position=position_dodge()) +     
  xlab("Year") + ylab("Energy Consumption")
```

[image]

Given the large gaps in scale, if you want both the population and the energy consumption on a same graph, IMO, energy consumption per capita is better suited.

Comment: Thanks Khashaa I actually wanted in the x axis the population estimate.

Comment: But I guess its fool hardy to represent soo much data in a barplot. Should I use a scatterplot and facet grid? I am very onfused how to represent this data.

Comment: @tootsie_1984 bar plots are meant to represent count data. If you're trying to show your data with population size, perhaps points and lines would tease out the effect of consumption.

Comment: Roman what do you suggest I do for this?? I am seeing that Bar plots wasnt a wise decision. Any idea what i should be doing?